# Python sorting string of numbers

Tags: python, list, sorting

I hava a little problem, specifically what I want to do is sort this kind of list

```
['520 0', '30000 1', '14000 2', '26273 3', '3829 4', '11776 5', '6947 6', '499 7',]
```

after the first occurring number. When I try the `sorted` method I'm not getting the right result, and I don't want to change the data type (because of later methods). I want to sort the strings by their algebraic values.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: can you please clarify in what way you want to clarify those strings?

Comment: How do you want the strings sorted? Show the desired output (and ideally your coding attempt)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
my_list = ['520 0', '30000 1', '14000 2', '26273 3', '3829 4', '11776 5', '6947 6', '499 7']

my_list.sort(key = lambda x: int(x.split()[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A =  ['520 0', '30000 1', '14000 2', '26273 3', '3829 4', '11776 5', '6947 6', '499 7'] 
print sorted(A, key=lambda x:int(x.split()[0]))
# ['499 7', '520 0', '3829 4', '6947 6', '11776 5', '14000 2', '26273 3', '30000 1']
```

What you're trying to do is called [natural sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order). You can use the `key` parameter of the [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand properly how you want to sort your list, but I think you can solve the problem passing a `key` function to the `sorted` function.

For instance, if you want to sort w.r.t. the first of the numbers, you shuold go with something like

```
sorted(l, key=lambda s: int(s.split(' ')[0]))
```